# How to bypass typescript type check when props of OwnProps would auto merge by connect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I was trying to crab `collection` from url so I wrote code below

```js
// parent
<Route
  path={`${this.props.match.path}/:collection`}
  component={Collection}
/>

//child
interface MatchProps {
  collection: string;
}

interface OwnProps {
  routeProps: RouteComponentProps<MatchProps>;
}

const mapStateToProps = (
  state: StoreState,
  ownProps: OwnProps
): StateToProps => {
  console.log(ownProps);
  return {
    collection: selectCollection(ownProps.routeProps.match.params.collection)(state)
  };
};
```

which would raise error that `Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`, but if I change the type of `ownProps` to `RouteComponentProps<MatchProps>` and change the corresponding return statement, the code would work.
Both time, the console outputs the exact same result for match

```
match:
path: "/shop/:collection"
url: "/shop/hats"
isExact: true
params: {collection: "hats"}
```

After a digging and find out that connect would merge all props into the final set props.
But if I just code `ownProps.match` instead of `ownProps.routeProps.match`, it won't pass the typescript type check.
Any suggestion other than use `&` to union all types?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OwnProps are defined wrong. It needs to be:

```
interface OwnProps extends RouteComponentProps<MatchProps> {

}
```

because React-router Route component pushes his props directly to your props object it is not wrapped around a routeProps property.

This should also pass the TypeScript check :)